# Getting stat (ls or cp) of hidden files

Tags: linux, unix, dotfiles

I have a folder with a `.tmux.conf` file under source control, and I would like to copy that file over to `~`. Here is an `ls` of that:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-180:~$ ls -alh .vim/others
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K May  2 19:05 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K May  2 19:05 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  706 May  2 19:05 .tmux.conf
```

However, when I do `ls` on that directory, I get nothing:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-180:~$ ls .vim/others/*
ls: cannot access '.vim/others/*': No such file or directory
```

Same with `cp`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-180:~$ cp .vim/others/* .
cp: cannot stat '.vim/others/*': No such file or directory
```

Is there some additional parameter I have to add when copying over dot files?

Comment: The * expansion happens prior (by the shell), no? That is, the expansion fails (returning the original unexpanded value) and neither command understands wildcards - thus failing as there is indeed no file with that name containing a *.

Comment: [how to glob every hidden file except current and parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this command

```
ls -ld .[!.]*

ls -ld .vim/others/[!.]*
```